# How to get part of the string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
 var MapId ='Library://London/Maps/Main-Mobile.MapDefinition'
```

From string above I need to get this part:

```
 MapId ='Library://London/'
```

How can I do it with help of regex or jquery?

Comment: Start by trying to describe what the rules are in English, and then express them in regular expressions. Do you, for instance, need "The first 18 characters of the string"? Or "Everything before the word "Maps"? Or "Everything before and including the first `/` that appears after `//`"? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split()` and `slice()` operations:

```js
var MapId ='Library://London/Maps/Main-Mobile.MapDefinition';
MapId = MapId.split(/\//).slice(0,3).join('/') + '/';
console.log(MapId);
```